# Python (def) functions argument who switches IF NOT or just IF keywords

Tags: python

Example:

```
s = [1, 2]
def func(argument)":
   for x in s:
       argument x == 1:
           print(x)
```

If instead argument be just IF keyword, then result will be 1, but if instead argument be NOT IF keywords, then result will be 2.

I want make a function, in which I can to choose change if statements keywords.
How with functions argument make IF NOT or just IF keyword?

Comment: There are several problems here, like what you want to compare. It could be `if x == argument` or perhaps `if x != argument` ... but then what is the 1 for? Since you are still learning basic syntax, the standard [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) may help. And there are hundreds of classes, tutorials and books out there. Trying to learn this from questions here on stackoverflow is not as good as using these other resources. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat reading between the lines here, but you basically want this?

```
def foo(bar):
    if bar:
        if baz == 1:
            print(baz)
    elif not bar:
        if baz != 1:
            print(baz)
```

Of course that can be simplified:

```
def foo(bar = True):
    if (baz == 1) == bar:
        print(baz)
```

Note that this requires the parentheses, otherwise you'll get a chained comparison, which won't do what you might think.

Alternatively:

```
from operator import eq, ne

def foo(bar = True):
    op = (ne, eq)[bar]
    if op(baz, 1):
        print(baz)
```

That `(ne, eq)[bar]` can be written more explicitly as `eq if bar else ne`, or `if bar: op = eq else: op = ne`. [`operator.eq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.eq) and `operator.ne` are the function equivalents to `==` and `!=`.

This is also a possible alternative:

```
def foo(op = eq):
    if op(baz, 1):
        print(baz)
```

Then call the function like `foo(eq)`, `foo(ne)`, or with any other comparison function you want. This *may* be good idea in some circumstances, but maybe not as a general API design for generic functions.